# Why vue CSS priority rules don't work right?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Why css priority doesn't work right:

```
...
<body>
<div class="class1">
  <div attribute class="class2"></div>
</div>
</body>
...

div[attribute] {
  color: red;
}

.class1 .class2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

div with class2 will have color: red, but in priority rules color must be blue. This is vue feature?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this; in vue the element appears blue, as would be expected.  Are you sure you don't have other CSS rules that may be interfering?

Comment: No, this is not vue feature.
A little bit debugging in a browser can show better what's wrong with your css codes.
May be: `scoped` code causes something, or an "important" in global css form influences your local css codes. You should better debug it

Answer (score 0):

Text appears blue to me.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
    <div class="class1">
      <div attribute class="class2">Text</div>
    </div>`
})
```

```css
div[attribute] {
  color: red;
}

.class1 .class2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```